# To find minimum distance between two array PLOT1 and PLOT2 and also store the index where that point is

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

There are 2 array Plot1 is of form `plot1 = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] (1X4)`and we have tp find minimum distance of plot1 with plot2,(plot2 which have multiple array stored in it).We want O/P as 
            i)min distance among all points from plot2 (Smin)
           ii)Index  where point is stored
           iii)Index of array where point is stored 
My code works when plot2 is have one array in it.But fails when it have multiple array as

```
    plot2 = np.array([[(1.0, 4.0, 5.0),(4.0, 7.0, 90.0),(1.0, 4.0, 5.0)],
     [(2.9,3.2,3.3),(2.3,2.6,5.5),(2.4,3.5,4.4)],
     [(2.9,3.2,3.3),(2.3,2.6,5.5),(2.4,3.5,4.4)]])
```

So my working code is

```
import numpy as np


    plot1 = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
    plot2 = [(1.0, 4.0, 5.0),
             (4.0, 7.0, 90.0),
             (1.0, 4.0, 5.0),
             (-1.0, -4.0, -5.0)]



    indexes = []
    for i in range(len(plot2)):  # To get one element at a time from plot2
        plotk = plot2[i]
        S = np.linalg.norm(np.array(plot1) - np.array(plotk))
        print("Distance between plot1 and plotk is %f"  %(S))  # euclidian distance is calculated
        if (i == 0):
            Smin = S
            Sminant = S
            indexes.append(i)
        else:
            if (S < Sminant):
                Smin = S
                Sminant=Smin
                indexes = []
                indexes.append(i)
            elif (S == Sminant):
                indexes=[]
                indexes.append(i)

    print('indexes:')
    print(indexes)

    for i in range(len(indexes)):
       print("VAlues of Slist with min  \n",indexes[i], plot2[indexes[i]],Smin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do, I edit my answer so it answers your question:

```
row,col,n=plot2.shape

S=np.empty([row,col])
for i_row in range(row):
    for i_col in range(col):
        plotk = plot2[i_row,i_col]
        S[i_row,i_col] = np.linalg.norm(np.array(plot1) - np.array(plotk))

np.min(S)
ind = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(S, axis=None), S.shape)
```

Comment: But it will not give me the index of array(or group) in which point is stored

Answer (score 0):

You use `import numpy as np` but make no use of it... Let's see what we can can use from the vast arsenal of `numpy` methods (the key is the [`argmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) method...)

```
In [10]: from numpy import abs, argmin, array

In [11]: plot1 = array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
    ...: plot2 = array([(1.0, 4.0, 5.0),
    ...:                (4.0, 7.0, 90.0),
    ...:                (1.0, 4.0, 5.0),
    ...:                (-1.0, -4.0, -5.0)])

In [12]: adiff = abs(plot1-plot2)

In [13]: adiff
Out[13]: 
array([[ 0.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  5., 87.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  6.,  8.]])

In [14]: indices = argmin(adiff, axis=1)

In [15]: indices
Out[15]: array([0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Eventually it is possible to use the `indices` to have the values of the minima

```
In [17]: adiff[range(adiff.shape[0]), indices]
Out[17]: array([0., 3., 0., 2.])
```

The `range(adiff.shape[0])` gives the number of each row in turns, matching the content of `indices` that indicates the column that, in each row, contains the minimum.